# How to disable Bootstrap's Button dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Link here: [bootstrap button dropdowns](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns)

I'd like to disable this button dropdown, i added `disabled` class to `<a>` but the dropdown can still be opened by clicking the dropdown button. Any ideas?

Comment: If you could post some corresponding code.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add `disabled` class to the button...

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That works when editing via bootstraps site. I did notice that they're not using the anchor like their example.

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
```

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing this, i change to use <button> and it works, i think this may be a bug of Bootstrap's doc.

Comment: Be careful this only makes the button LOOK disabled (regardless of using A or BUTTON tags), the JS functionality remains enabled on many browsers including IE11 and Chrome, see [BS3 Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#callout-buttons-disabled-anchor)

Comment: I would add: in case you are using some other inner element like an icon, remember to disable both of them otherwise the dropdown menu will still show up.

Answer (score 16):

Yeah you can do it this way:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').data('toggle', '');
```

This works only when it gets this property: `data-toggle="dropdown"`, You can either change the `dropdown` to `''` blank one.

Or you can try and remove the attr of `data-toggle`

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').removeAttr('data-toggle');
```

Answer (score 9):

All you need to do is set the disabled property of the button.

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').prop('disabled', true);
```

[http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons Disabled state](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons)