# How can I disable bootstrap dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a dropdown list using bootstrap.Dynamically I want to disable and enable the dropdown list.

html code:

```
  <div class="span3 offset1">
        <select name="primary" class="select-block" id="select_alert" style="display: none;">
            <option "selected"="">Choose Alert T</option>                         


    <option value="T1">T1</option>

    <option value="T2">T2</option>

    <option value="T3">T3</option>

    <option value="T4">T4</option>

</select>
<div class="btn-group select select-block">
  <i class="dropdown-arrow dropdown-arrow-primary"></i>
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle clearfix btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" id="select_alert">
    <span class="filter-option pull-left">Choose Alert T</span>&nbsp;
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" role="menu">
    <li rel="0" class="selected">
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="">
        <span class="pull-left">Choose Alert T</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li rel="1">
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="">
        <span class="pull-left">T1</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li rel="2">
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="">
        <span class="pull-left">T2</span></a>
    </li>
    <li rel="3">
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="">
        <span class="pull-left">T3</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li rel="4">
      <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="">
        <span class="pull-left">T4</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

some times I want to disable and sometimes I want to enable.So How can I do this.
In this I have 2 more dropdown elemnts.All are placed in singlw `div` tag.Here I didn't mention that `div` tag id name.I just putted single dropdown element  code.

Comment: Add a disabled class to the button. duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697968/how-to-disable-bootstraps-button-dropdown)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, by jquery you can get this:

Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jV7ye/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chkdwn2").click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
          $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);
       } else {
          $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);  
       }
    });
});
```

**UPDATED** JS CODE as per your need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        if(!$("#chkdwn2").is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#dropdown").prop("disabled",true);
        }

        $("#chkdwn2").click(function() {
           if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
              $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);
           } else {
              $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);  
           }
        });
    });
```

Replace `dropdown` id with your id. Thanks

Comment: I your jsFiddle code,interchange trur->false and false->true.That means Initially I want to disabled.it's not working.

Comment: Have you clicked on "Run" after interchanging true and false?

Comment: Please paste this code in javascript and try again:

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    if(!$("#chkdwn2").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#dropdown").prop("disabled",true);
    }
    
    $("#chkdwn2").click(function() {
       if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
          $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", false);
       } else {
          $("#dropdown").prop("disabled", true);  
       }
    });
});

Answer (score 3):

By using jquery we can do

Disable Dropdown

```
$('.select_alert').attr('data-toggle','');
```

Enable Dropdown

```
$('.select_alert').attr('data-toggle','dropdown');
```

Comment: Initially I want to dropdowns after than enable.I tried your code in web-console page.it's working fine.that same code I pasted in my .js file.here it's not working.

Comment: you dont need to paste on js file.write seperate function to enable and disable and call that function sure it work

Comment: I made a function, Initially I passed data-toggle value is null("") to that function.If I call function I am getting the following error. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of undefined `.

Answer (score 0):

If above solutions does not work for you, the try

```
$('#yourDropDownElement').prop('disabled', true).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

I'm using boostrap v 3.3.6

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by add if block on the property and add disabled class to the drop down.

below is my div in that i have eanbled/disabled dropdown toggle button on IsNewEditDisabled

```
<button ng-if="!IsNewEditDisabled" class="btn dropdown-toggle" ng-class="{open: status.isopen}" dropdown-toggle>
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i><span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button ng-if="IsNewEditDisabled" class="btn dropdown-toggle disabled" ng-class="{open: status.isopen}" dropdown-toggle>
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i><span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
```