# Prevent Bootstrap dropdown menu toggle on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This was asked quite a few times before, but I can't find a proper solution yet. I am toggling navbar dropdown menus *on hover* with the following code:

```
$(".nav .dropdown").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
});
```

which works just fine. However, clicking on the `.dropdown-toggle` button toggles the menu as well, which I want to avoid. Any suggestions on the code?

Comment: can you make fiddle for issue?

Comment: one solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15698013/2269262

Comment: `$('.dropdown-toggle').on('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault()});`

Answer (score 2):

Just stop the propagation here:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Comment: In bootstrap 4, the dropdown event is tied directly to the `.dropdown-toggle` div, so this unfortunately doesn't work.